# can we install a hypervisor inside a OS created by another hypervisor?

Tags: server, linux-kernel, vps, kvm, hypervisor

I know title sounds little crazy but I was wondering, if we install KVM on server and create a VPS having a Linux OS then, can we install KVM module in a newly created VPS and again create a VPS inside a VPS ?

Comment: It is simple to try than to ask. Probably you can do it, but you lose all support of CPU, so it will be much slower. AFAIK no hypervisor is made to cooperate with inside hypervisor

Comment: Inside the inner VM you can run VLC playing "Inception"

Answer (score 1):

Nested virtualization creates all sorts of problems.  Some of the virtualization experts, like vmware, have figured it out; but basically the common problem is page tables.

The *client* has a set of page tables. The addresses generated through those become the inputs to the *monitors* page tables; this is enforced by the cpu.  This is an important optimization, even though a simple memory access might cause up to ~ 24 translations, thus potential memory accesses.

When you attempt to nest the monitor, however, things go awry.  You cannot convince the processor to invoke an endless list of nested page tables.  Well, you can, and someday intel might, but they are known for transistor count, not design.

To handle this, the monitor has to sensitize itself to the clients page tables.  This might seem difficult, but is similar to virtualizing a device. The client offers up a small set of addresses for the base page tables.  As the monitor, you simply create a shadow set, and verify every page table entry, and sensitize yourself to modifications in any of the interior nodes of the collective page tables.  From that point on, synchronization is trap -> update.

For the rest of it, it is the same, you have to (hand) virtualize the other mechanisms, which varies from ghastly (intel) to kinda-cute (arm).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called "nested virtualization" and the answer is: it depends :)
From my understanding that's possible on intel but, for example in arm64, this is still under development. Anyway I think although nested virtualization is interesting from the technical point of view, it's not widely used.

Comment: Some modern OSes (windows, macos) run in hv, so that critical updates are not actually performed by the kernel, but rather a microkernel running in the hv.  Thus host based hypervisors (virtualbox, fusion, ...) actually need to run nested.